# Websphere application server VS Jboss

Tags: jboss, websphere

I am looking for a kind of java ee application server. My company is using Websphere application server and I am reviewing jboss. I am not familiar with WAS, would anybody like to tell me which outstanding features provided by IBM WAS? And what the common features between WAS and JBOSS.

I write down my understanding firstly.

IBM WAS Outstanding(Specified) features:
1. LTAP 
2. Monitor Tool
3. IDE(RAD)   --- not sure is it free?
4. Integration with IBM portal(since we are using this product as well)
5. Integration with IBM MQ(above reason)
6. Webservice extension support(WS_*)
7. .....cool websphere library??? no idea, who would give me a sample?

Common features in WAS and JBOSS
1. Vendor service support
2. Java EE and EJB 3.0
3. Clustering
4. Any reasonable features for web2.0 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' think you should make comparison this way. Get the IBM team to provide you their list and speak to RedHat and get their list and then make the comparison.

RAD is not free by any means.

WAS is a good stack as it has a good track record in high volume sites and is the foundation of a number of IBM products (e.g Process Server, Portal Server etc).

The flipside of WAS is the learning curve is steep and the machine requirements are steep too.
Historically WAS was lagging in the support for latest versions of Java EE. Things are improving these days though

HTH

Manglu